# How does an automotive Mass Air Flow (MAF) sensor circuit start up?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, sensor, automotive, comparator

The transistor needs voltage from the amplifier to turn on, but it can't provide it since the transistor is not allowing current to flow through the bridge transistors.

[image: MAF SENSOR]

Comment: There's probably more to the circuit than is shown on your diagram.

Comment: No doubt the amplifier output is constrained to be now lower than some minimum amount necessary to get the thing started up and working.  That is definitely not a full schematic.

Comment: The amplifier is not powered from the A & B nodes it's measuring. It's also connected to B+ & ground for power.